# gnome settings lost after installing xournal and Glib2

Tags: debian, gnome3

I have Debian (jessie)

```
$uname -a
Linux nn 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u1 (2016-09-03) x86_64 
GNU/Linux

$lsb_release -irc
Distributor ID: Debian
Release:    8.6
Codename:   jessie
```

I recently install xournal (and also Glib2).

After reboot all my gnome-desktop-settings disappeared. For instance, Language bar, preferences for terminal, the behavior of touchpad. Another problem was that I couldn't  set new parameters because whenever I was doing that they were not permanent. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The following solution worked!
https://askubuntu.com/questions/558446/my-dconf-gsettings-installation-is-broken-how-can-i-fix-it-without-ubuntu-reins

It seems that xournal or/and Glib meshes with search paths for dynamic libraries. 
After the following (as suggested in one answer)

`sudo mv /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d/xuserlocal.conf
sudo ldconfig
sudo shutdown -r now`

I got back all my original settings.